# How to set multiple key-value pairs to one cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using this line to set multiple key-value pair at once to one cookie

```
document.cookie="username=John Smith; test1=ew; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
```

it seemed `test1` is not set to the cookie successfully, because when I write `document.cookie` in the console, it didn't print this key-value pair. Anyone know how to **set multiple key-value pair** to **ONE cookie**?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It does not make sense to store multiple key-value pairs into one cookie, because by definition **a cookie represents one key-value pair**.

I believe you don't understand well [how `document.cookie` works](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script). It is not a standard JS string: when you set it, the cookie definition it contains is **appended** to the list of existing cookies. That is, you cannot set two cookies at the same time using this API.

You have two solutions:

- Use a cookie for each key-value you want to store:

  ```
  document.cookie = "myCookie=myValue";
  document.cookie = "myOtherCookie=myOtherValue";
  ```
- Store a single cookie with a custom serialization of your complex data, for example JSON:

  ```
  document.cookie = "myCookie=" + JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar', baz: 'poo'});
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Actually i think it would be better to use
`document.cookie = "myCookie=foo='bar'&baz='poo'; here is the rest of cookie specifications if you like..."`
as far as i know, it also is compatible with `Asp` and `Asp.Mvc` on server side:
`string foo=Request.Cookies["myCookie"]["foo"]`