# How do you save multiple key value pairs to one cookie with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, key-value

I have a form with multiple checkboxes in it and when I click them, I want to add/remove the key-value pairs (name of the input + true/false) in one single cookie.

When I click on the checkboxes only the first pair gets shown in console.log.

This is what I ended up with so far:

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
    <input class="input" name="expert_id_1" type="checkbox" />
    <input class="input" name="expert_id_2" type="checkbox" />
    <input class="input" name="expert_id_3" type="checkbox" />
    <input class="input" name="expert_id_4" type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function setCookie() {
    var customObject = {};
    var inputName = $('.input').attr('name');
    customObject[inputName] = $('.input').prop('checked');
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(customObject);
    document.cookie = 'cookieObject=' + jsonString;
    console.log(jsonString);
}

function getCookie() {
    var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split('=');
    var customObject = JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]);
    $('.input').prop('checked') = customObject[inputName];
}

$('.input').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).attr('value', 'true');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('value', 'false');
        }
        setCookie();
    });
});
```

Comment: Cookies can only store Text so I would `JSON.stringify()` to then store an array or object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set multiple key-value pairs to one cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865916/how-to-set-multiple-key-value-pairs-to-one-cookie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cookie is being overrided and it might only store the first checkbox info. Also to set the prop value, you have to pass it as a second parameter.

This should update the cookie when clicked and also be able to set the values from the cookie.

```js
function updateCookie($input) {
    var cookieObject = getCookieObject();
    var inputName = $input.attr('name');
    cookieObject[inputName] = $input.attr('value');
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(cookieObject);
    document.cookie = 'cookieObject=' + jsonString;
    console.log(jsonString);
}

function setFromCookie(){
    var cookieObject = getCookieObject();
    for(var inputName in cookieObject)
        if(cookieObject.hasOwnProperty(inputName))
            $(`.input[name="${inputName}"]`).prop('checked', cookieObject[inputName]);
}

function getCookieObject() {
    var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split('=');
    var cookieObject = {};
    if(nameValueArray.length >= 2)
        cookieObject = JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]);
    return cookieObject;
}

$('.input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.on('click', function() {
        $this.attr('value', String($this.is(':checked')))
        updateCookie($this);
    });
});
```

Although I would recomend you to use a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object to encode and decode the parameters, since you are relying on the fact that `"="` is not inside the JSON string.

Comment: Thank you Haibrayn González, this seem to solve my problem.

Comment: I would like to add a function which will be run on document ready to check only the checkboxes with the value "true" from the Cookie but I could'nt figure it out how to filter out the elements.