# How to add cookies to protractor with multiple value

Tags: cookies, protractor, mocha.js

So I am working on getting authentication to work with cookies as a security reason and I have getting thoughts to add the values inside a cookies which should "bypass" the first login part so I dont need to use the basic authentication login.

So I got these cookies to use:

```
name: auth, value: { "usr": "admin" "pwd": "password" }
```

so what I did was:

```
browser.get("https://www.testingmysite.com");
browser.manage().addCookie({name: 'auth', value: 'usr': 'admin', 'pwd': 'password' })
```

but that returns:

```
    browser.manage().addCookie({name: 'auth', value: 'usr': 'admin', 'pwd': 'password' })
                                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

and I have no idea anymore waht to do to be able to send those values into the cookie so I can skip the basic authentication login.

How can I do that?

Comment: By definition "a cookie represents one key-value pair." https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866121/1859890 but you can save a json string with JSON.stringify({ "usr": "admin", "pwd": "password" })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass a `IWebDriverOptionsCookie` ([ref](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cbcfdd4b12b863a82f5f1903c47fe22fa3b6975c/types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts#L1393)) object to `addCookie()`. In your case do something like:

```js
browser.manage().addCookie({ name: 'auth', value: '{ "usr": "admin", "pwd": "password" }' });
```